# Using SQL Server 2008, I have a hard coded two tiered case statement that I want to put into a reference table

Tags: sql-server-2008, case

Querying appointment booking data using SQL Server 2008.
Appointment durations are largely hard-coded depending on the Clinic and appointment type as per this sample:

```
case when cl.ClinicCode like 'FPLAS%' then case when apt.AppointmentTypeName in ('New','Time Critical','Emergency') then 20 else 10 end
    when cl.ClinicCode like 'SPLAS%' then case when apt.AppointmentTypeName in ('New','Time Critical','Emergency') then 20 else 10 end
else 30 end as duration
```

I want to remove the coding and create a table to store this information.  The problem I have is that there are about 50 potential values for apt.AppointmentTypeName which I do not want to repeat for each of the 400 different ClinicCodes.  How do I best deal with the "else" part of the embedded AppointmentTypeName case statement?

Answer (score 0):

Just store the ones you want. Anything that doesn't match returns NULL. Convert this NULL to 30

I have many assumptions here. I could make less if you posted all of your code.

```
SELECT ISNULL(AppointmentTime.Duration,30) As Duration
FROM YourTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN
AppointmentTime
ON cl.ClinicCode LIKE AppointmentTime.Lookup1
AND apt.AppointmentTypeName = AppointmentTime.Lookup2
```

You may also wish to store this default value of 30 in the same table